# Admin panel is not working due to session

Tags: php

Sudden my website admin panel no longer works and i've tired many ways to edit it and all are faild.

Please show me where the error should be

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE `egadmin` (
`AdminID` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`username` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`AdminID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `egadmin` VALUES (1, 'admin', 'pass');
```

**conn.php [connection file]**

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "mypass";
$db_name = "dbname";
$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection);
?>
```

**index.php [Login Form]**

```
<form action="validate.php" method="post">
ID <input type="text" name="userid" id="userid" />
Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**validate.php [Login form send it to validate.php]**

```
<?php
require_once("conn.php");

$user = $_POST["userid"];
$pass = sha1($_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM egadmin WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  session_start();
  header("Cache-control: private");
  $_SESSION["access"] = "granted";
  header("Location: secure.php");
} else
  header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

**secure.php [Should be the protected file]**

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Cache-control: private");
if ($_SESSION["access"] == "granted")
echo "blah blah blah";
else
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

***The problem***

every time i enter correct login informations (username,password) it keep resend me to login form (index.php) so it looks like it can not create $_SESSION at all.

Any help please how to fix it or why that error

Note : PHP Version 5.2.17 | register_globals = On (also not working if it Off)

Comment: try putting session_start() in your validate.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to compare a encrypted password to a non encrypted password. Make sure the pass in the database is also encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

When you are checking if the password is same as in the database you are hashing it with sha1 function, while the value in the database is not hashed.

Update the database with the query

```
UPDATE egadmin SET password = SHA1(password);
```